# ASP.NET MVC @Html.DropDownList Using a List to edit item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, dropdown, viewbag

I am trying to use a `@Html.DropDownList` with a custom list. The Problem is when I go to Edit an Entry, It's default is the first item in the list but I would like it to be the value it originally is. When I don't use the Viewbag, It pre selects the item it originally is.

Here is the ViewBag I am using.

```
    ViewBag.AreaEmployeeEdit= db.Areas
          .OrderBy(s => s.Site.SiteName)
          .Select(s => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = s.AreaID.ToString(),
              Text = s.Site.SiteName + " " + "||" + " " + s.Area1
          });
```

And here it is in the Edit Form.

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaID, "Area", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("AreaID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AreaEmployeeEdit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not setting the model for the `DropDownList`

your edit should be like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AreaID, "Area", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AreaEmployeeEdit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AreaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I replaced `"AreaID"` with `model => model.AreaID`.